# Is it possible to show multiple pins and direction for each points in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview

Is it possible to show directions from one point to another point recursively until i reach the destination from source point like Route or Path from Source to Destination in iPhone using MKMapVIew.

I tried with MKOverlayPath and MKpolyline but not able to proceed.

Please help me in this issue?

Answer (score 1):

hello hope this will help you..
download this [demo](https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes) with this you can find the direction of the 2 position in map view and than you can use timer for updating its location after each second so its seems like what you want..